# jQuery: Performing basic calculations on data contained inside HTML tables

Tags: jquery

I am working on a legacy site that is using tables to output data. What I would like to do is the following - but I am not sure how to go about doing this with jQuery.

**In the first column:** There is a dollar price of the unit (with class 'buyformunitprice')

**In the second column:** There is an input box that allows the user to enter a numeric quantity of the item. This column has the class 'buyformquantity'.

**In the third column:** This should display **first column * second column**. So if the user has entered in 10 items, and the price is $170 (obviously this could change) - then the value here would be $1700. This column has the class 'buyformunitpricetotal'

**So far I only have this HTML ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fakeguybrushthreepwood/R9eE7/)):**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="buyformcells buyformunitprice">$170</td>
<td class="buyformcells buyformquantity"><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
<td class="buyformcells buyformunitpricetotal"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Basic calculations (as you've specified) - read some tutorials... http://jsfiddle.net/R9eE7/1/

Comment: Thanks @scrowler, I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/R9eE7/4/

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="buyformcells buyformunitprice">$170</td>
    <td class="buyformcells buyformquantity"><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
<td class="buyformcells buyformunitpricetotal"></td>
</tr>
```

```
$('input[name=quantity]').blur(function(){
if ($(this).attr('value').length > 0) {
     var price = parseInt($('.buyformunitprice').text().replace('$', ''));
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
    var total = price * quantity;
    $('.buyformunitpricetotal').html(total);
}
```

});

I attach a blur event to the textbox (will fire when the user clicks off the textbox). check to make sure that the user has entered some input to the textbox by checking length, then convert the values to integers. You may want to ad some error checking to make sure the value in the textbox is an int. Then update the total column's hmtl.

Comment: See updated fiddle, this will work on multiple rows/columns and only update the row/column being edited http://jsfiddle.net/R9eE7/10/

Answer (score 1):

This is another option to do calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/R9eE7/9/

On html script, I am attaching id to input and td element to allow jQuery able to retrieve the value.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="buyformcells buyformunitprice">$170</td>
        <td class="buyformcells buyformquantity">
            <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity">
        </td>
        <td id="total" class="buyformcells buyformunitpricetotal"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- insert the price into calc function 1st parameter -->
<button onclick="calc(170, parseInt($('#quantity').val()))">Calculate</button>
```

And the calc function

```
function calc(price, quantity) {       
    $("#total").html(price * quantity);
}
```